# How to plot a graph to see trend between each month and candidates left rate

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I have dataframe which has month vise column along with candidates left rate . i need to see the trend basically like a seasonality to see how the attrition rate is going.

DF

```
Date         Candidate_%
01-07-2021   20.9%
01-08-2021   15.9%
01-09-2021   14.8%
01-10-2021   14.09%
01-11-2021   12.89%
01-12-2021   7.5%
01-01-2022   9.6%
```

....         ....
01-04-2023  8.5%

Date column is datetime64[ns] data type
Candidate_% is in datetime64[ns] data type

Tried code:

```
sns.lineplot(x='Date',y='Candidate_%',data=df,hue='Month_Year')
```

or

```
df.plot(x="Date", y=("Candidate_%"), style="o")
```

But none of them works as expected to see the trend.

Expected :
Date vise ( Month  x axis) vise  plot to check the trend  with candidate_% as y axis and lines which can give years to check the trend

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try something like this :

```
(
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Date", y=df["Candidate_%"].str.rstrip("%").astype(float),
                 hue=df["Date"].str[-4:]).tick_params(axis="x", rotation=30)
)
```

Output :

[image]